# Weird link behaviour when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a different behaviour on the first click with an anchor tag, it is opposed to click 2nd,3rd,4th..clicks.

Having the href value set to `" "`, I do not get a HTTP GET on the first click.I Can't see why the first click should have any other behaviour than click no 2 (and upwards).

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick='alert("clicked")'>Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onclick='alert("clicked")'>Menu Item 2</a></li>
</ul>

</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#container").contextMenu({
        menu: 'menu'
    });
});​
```

I use jquery plugin to create a rightclick contextmenu

Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtVandelay/DVpAV/) to illustrate the issue. 
The first click does not fire an HTTP GET, but if open the menu again and then click. It fires off as expected.

Comment: You might want to try with return false on your anchor tag, and call a js function in your empty href

Comment: If the a tag isn't actually linking anywhere, why even include the href attribute?

Comment: To allow the text between the anchor tags to be interpreted as a clickable link. But this is only for test purpose, the issue is that the HTTP_GET is not begin fired on first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onSelect event for the contextMenu to do your magic.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#container").contextMenu({
    menu: 'menu',
    onSelect: function(e) { alert('this is where you want your logic');}
});
```

});​

Answer (score 2):

In your click handler for menu items (which is currently a call to alert()), you should do `event.preventDefault();` to stop the browser from following the link. Even though, the `href=""` is empty, the browser is still thinking it is a call to a new page and reloading the page.

You can also use the old technique of null anchor tag using `href="#"`. This will not cause the browser to load a new URL.

Comment: That does not explain why the behaviour on first click is different from the second, third,..and so on. The empty href is for "test" only. The behaviour I want to accomplish is to have the anchor tag do a HTTP_GET on the first click (not only on second, third)